# Mounting Time Machine .sparsebundle fails

Tags: time-machine, backup

I have a Time Machine backup volume that is not mountable anymore. I tried to repair it with:

```
fsck_hfs -drfy /dev/disk1s2
```

It showed the following error:

```
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
Invalid catalog PEOF
(4, 0)
** The volume   could not be verified completely.
volume check failed with error 7 
volume type is pure HFS+ 
primary MDB is at block 0 0x00 
alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00 
primary VHB is at block 2 0x02 
alternate VHB is at block 399999998 0x17d783fe 
sector size = 512 0x200 
VolumeObject flags = 0x07 
total sectors for volume = 400000000 0x17d78400 
total sectors for embedded volume = 0 0x00 
CheckHFS returned -1317, fsmodified = 0
```

How can I repair it and retrieve the data from the last backup?